# I need to use the Boolean value true or false to tell the user if his/her guess was correct

Tags: java

I had to make a code where the user guesses the number the computer picks. I need to also use Boolean value true or false to tell the user if the user is correct or not. I tried using if else statement, but I have not learned that in Java yet. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomGuessMatch
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       boolean right = true;
       int MAX = 5;
       int MIN = 1;
       int guess;
       int random;
       Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Input your guess between 1 through 5.");
           guess = ask.nextInt();
       random = MIN + (int)(Math.random() * MAX);
       System.out.println("Your guess was " + guess);
       System.out.println("The random number was " + random);
       if (right = 



    }
}
```

Comment: `boolean correct = guess == random;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read about if else in java. That is conditional statements.
 It is like if you want to perform something when some condition is true, else if the condition is not satisfied it will execute else part.

```
if(condition) {
  //Some task
} else {
  // some task
}
```

Like you can add if else in your code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomGuessMatch
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       boolean right = true;
       int MAX = 5;
       int MIN = 1;
       int guess;
       int random;
       Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Input your guess between 1 through 5.");
           guess = ask.nextInt();
       random = MIN + (int)(Math.random() * MAX);
       System.out.println("Your guess was " + guess);
       System.out.println("The random number was " + random);
       if (guess == random) {
            right = true;
       } else {
            right = false;
       }
       System.out.println(right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should google more, for such a simple question. [For example](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_conditions.asp).

Anyway:

If the variable `right` is a `Boolean`:

```
  if (right) {
     // do something
  }
```